# Rest Android security technology choice

Tags: android, security, rest, jakarta-ee, oauth

Iam  building Webservice (using J2EE) along with an android Client. now Iam facing with which security technology to choose? and integrate it with my Rest services.
I crawled google and suggestion are about Oauth2.0, Basic authentication using TLS, api key.
In my android application used HttpClient i dont if integration one of these solution will require great changes in my code. By this occasion can anyone could make me a great description of the two first ones with suggestion of best tutorials with example ....

Comment: `can anyone could make me a great description of the two first ones with suggestion of best tutorials with example ?` Google is very useful for that

Comment: for the 3 shemes which is best?

Answer (score 2):

```
public class DataLoader {
DefaultHttpClient sslClient;
private boolean silent;

public class CustomX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
            throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(
            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
            throws CertificateException {
    }

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }
}

public class CustomSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    public CustomSSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException,
            KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);
        TrustManager tm = new CustomX509TrustManager();
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
    }

    public CustomSSLSocketFactory(SSLContext context)
            throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(null);
        sslContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port,
            boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host,
                port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }
}

public HttpResponse execute(HttpUriRequest request) {
    if (!(silent)) {
        Log.i("Performing request", "Performing request");
        for (Header header : request.getAllHeaders())
            Log.i("Performing request",
                    "Performing request "
                            + new StringBuilder()
                                    .append("Request header: ")
                                    .append(header.getName()).append(" - ")
                                    .append(header.getValue()).toString());
    }
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new CustomX509TrustManager() },
                new SecureRandom());
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        SSLSocketFactory ssf = new CustomSSLSocketFactory(ctx);
        ssf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        ClientConnectionManager ccm = client.getConnectionManager();
        SchemeRegistry sr = ccm.getSchemeRegistry();
        sr.register(new Scheme("https", ssf, 443));
        sslClient = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, client.getParams());
        response = sslClient.execute(request);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

}

Comment: Hey my friend please use this class. It will help you to overcome from all security isuues, Thanks

Comment: hi your code above imply iam using TLS/SSL certificate on the Rest server. right? how to enable ssl over Rest on glassfish 4.0? how to get the certificate to use with your class?

Comment: You have developed one servlet. Right? It is nothing but a web page. If you want SSL enabled webpage then you must purchase SSL certificate after that install that certificate. If you don't have that certificate then do use above mentioned code. Above mentioned code is appropriate for all security issues.Please upvote if you are satisfied. Thanks.

Comment: Iam  not using servlet iam bulding Rest service using jersey framework over http but i dont know to integrate https with it or using oauth feature for security. i dont want aouth anymore because it use third party server for authencation. so how to enable ssl/TLS on Rest service side

Comment: You have to buy the SSL/TSL certificate from companies like verisign and thawte. Thanks